# MYSQL query to sum upp all values from a certain fields

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table with columns:

`db_name` and `verb`

The table is holding the usage data of all requests may by the certain database.

The query I'm using now is:

```
SELECT db_name, verb, COUNT(*) FROM request GROUP BY db_name, verb order by db_name
```

Which returns:

[image]

But what I would like to have, is for the query to return all distinct db_name with summed up all distinct verbs.

Something like:

```
db_name      GET    POST   DELETE   UPDATE
username0     99      89      100     8299
username1     19      33      120     3111
```

How should I do this, or where should I look?

Comment: If a new verb suddenly is inserted, is that expected to show up in the expected result? (Or will it always be GET, POST, DELETE and UPDATE?)

Comment: It will always be those 4 verbs, and nothing else.

Comment: The database is MYSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a convenient syntax for conditional counts:

```
SELECT db_name, 
       SUM(verb = 'GET') as cnt_get,
       SUM(verb = 'POST') as cnt_post,
       SUM(verb = 'DELETE') as `cnt_delete,
       SUM(verb = 'UPDATE') as `cnt_update
FROM request
GROUP BY db_name
ORDER BY db_name;
```

Specifically, MySQL treats boolean values as numbers in an arithmetic context, with `1` for true and `0` for false.  That makes it easy to sum up the values.

Comment: thank you so much, that's exactly what I ment

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are talking about MSSQL? It depends on SQL Server version you are but one way could be with PIVOTS.

Pivot in SQL Server: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f0b2ed/pivot-and-unpovit-in-sql-server/

[EDIT]
So its MYSQL. In that case I would suggest Kazi's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have only four verb then you can use below query:

```
select db_name ,sum(case when verb='GET' then 1 else 0 end)    [GET],
                sum(case when verb='POST' then 1 else 0 end)   [POST],
                sum(case when verb='DELETE' then 1 else 0 end) [DELETE],
                sum(case when verb='UPDATE' then 1 else 0 end) [UPDATE]
from request 
group by db_name
```

Comment: You'd better _delimit_ the column aliases, since at least `DELETE` and `UPDATE` are reserved words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words